# Bootstrap labels overlap before stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a form with Boostrap 3's `form-horizontal` and using the grid system `col-md-*` to keep the labels and inputs aligned. It displays correctly when the browser window is 1200px or more wide, but when less and the media queries kick in, the labels attached to each input overlap the inputs to the left of them, instead of keeping apart or stacking vertically.

See this pen: https://codepen.io/chrisjbird/pen/XgZmZe

How do I stop them overlapping?

Comment: add `input { max-width:100%; }`

Comment: @APAD1 That's the simplest answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `TextBox` Is Overlapping So You can increase the width of `textbox` and give the `margin:12px`**

```
input{
margin :12px;
max-width:100%;  
}
```

```css
input{
margin:12px;
max-width:100%;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="http://mess/cgi-bin/websms/addmsg" target="iframe">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1" for="username">username:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            </div>
            <label class="col-md-1" for="password">password:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
        </div>
  
  
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1" for="app">app:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="app" name="app">
            </div>
            <label class="col-md-1" for="origin">origin:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="origin" name="origin">
            </div>
        </div>
  
  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1" for="sender">sender:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="sender" name="sender">
            </div>
            <label class="col-md-1" for="depart">depart:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="depart" name="depart">
            </div>
        </div>
  
  
  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1" for="destno">destno:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="destno" name="destno">
            </div>
        </div>
  
  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1" for="valperiod">valperiod:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="valperiod" name="valperiod">
            </div>
            <label class="col-md-1" for="priority">priority:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="priority" name="priority">
            </div>
        </div>
  
  
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="debug">Debug info
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

> **NOTE:** REMOVE `row` form `form-group` this code

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-1" for="app">app:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" id="app" name="app">
                </div>
                <label class="col-md-1" for="origin">origin:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" id="origin" name="origin">
                </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That does the trick - I wonder why an input is not already `max-width: 100%` in Bootstrap? BTW, the extra `row` class was left behind in error, thanks for pointing it out though. `row` is implied by `horizontal-form`, so removing it has no effect

Comment: @drkvogel ... yaa if you only remove `row` then  also get perfect result. but good you to give max-width to text box.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `<div class="form-group">` tag has a `row` class on it, removed that and it'll stack just like the others.

You also have both Bootstrap 3 and 4 loaded onto that pen, you should remove BS4 as it could cause some issues.